# Herb Sutter's article on making virtual functions private

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I read Herb Sutter's article http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm on virtual functions and how they should be declared private by default. Making a virtual function public would make it serve as an interface and customizer, and the suggestion is to separate the interfacing from the customization behavior, as the article suggests.

```
class shape
{
  protected:
    void set_area(double area)
    {
      area = area;
    };
  private:
    double area;
    virtual void compute_area() = 0;
};
class square
{

  private:
    double length;
    void compute_area()
    {
      set_area(length*length);
    }
};
```

If we consider these classes, we see that we can never call the area function from outside of either class because they are made to be virtual since we don't want the virtual function to serve as the interface between the class and the "outside world" as Sutter suggested. If I understand him correctly, to use the template method, and if I want to compute the area on a `shape` object, I'd need to provide a public non-virtual function to `shape` class. So something like this?

```
class shape
{
  public:
    void interfacer()
    {
      compute_area();
    }
  protected:
    void set_area(double area)
    {
      area = area;
    };
  private:
    double area;
    virtual void compute_area() = 0;
}
```

Doesn't that seem redundant over being able to just simply do:

```
shape *ptr = new square();
ptr->compute_area();
```

if we were to make the virtual function public?

I reread the article and he said the public virtuals should be "Rarely if ever" used. I wonder if he would think the above is one of those instances where it'd be appropriate to make the virtual function public instead of private.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps some more dogmatic person might disagree with me but I don't agree with the article. A private pure virtual method is implementable by a child class but not _callable_ by the child class. I seriously question the usefulness of this, as it (in my opinion) begins to creep into spaghetti land. I've personally never done nor seen this idiom used in the wild. Further, the idea that you wrap all virtual methods in template methods is laughable to me, personally. It's optimized away and only further complicates and obscures the intent of the class, as you pointed out. It's subjective.

Comment: As for the argument that you can rearrange the internal API without affecting the external API, there are (IMO) much better ways to handle such cases. To do this as a rule violates the YAGTNI principle and thus isn't something I'd personally do. In my experience, the most clear, concise, minimal code (note: not _terse_, which negates "clear") is the best code. The author suggests writing 7 or 8 lines where 1 will do the same job - code is, after all, for humans.

Comment: Read again the paragraph starting `"But but but," some have objected ...`

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED Yeah I'm not sure how I feel about this in this use case. I run into a lot of use cases similar to this, but other times, I do run into use cases where my virtual function is never called from outside of the class, so making it private makes sense. Regarding your second comment, in the above code, would you have preferred to just make the `area` member variable `protected` so you can set it directly in the derived class instead of having it as `private` and having a `set_area` function to set the area?

Comment: @eerorika I've read the article. I mentioned one of his points myself - he uses it as a benefit, I instead say since it's optimized out it's thus not necessary. His second point is a fallacy - "it only takes a few more seconds so you should do it anyway". That's dogma, not pragma. Multiply this by hundreds of thousands of methods and you have class headers inflated to oblivion.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks. I actually missed that paragraph for some reason. That makes sense to me. However, as someone who struggles with coming up with good function names, I feel like I'd struggle with coming up with an intuitively named wrapper function for `compute_area()`.

Comment: @Iamanon Give the public interface function a good name. Name the private virtual functions implementing it with same name suffixed with `_impl`  for example if you cannot come up with anything more meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

You understood correctly. You have to provide a public non-virtual function that calls the virtual function.

You seem to be asking what is the point of this: why have users call a public function that calls the private implementation rather than just having one function that does the work? Herb answers this in the post:

> First, note that the base class is now in complete control of its interface and policy, and can enforce interface preconditions and postconditions, insert instrumentation, and do any similar work all in a single convenient reusable place - the nonvirtual interface function. ...
>
> Second, when we've better separated interface and implementation, we're free to make each take the form it naturally wants to take instead of trying to find a compromise that forces them to look the same. For example, ...
>
> Third, the base class is now less fragile in the face of change. We are free to change our minds later and add pre- and postcondition checking, or separate processing into more steps, or refactor, or implement a fuller interface/implementation separation using the Pimpl idiom[4], or make other modifications to Widget's customizability, without affecting the code that uses Widget. ...

In general, many of the benefits of writing properly factored code only become truly apparent when it comes time to make the code more complex.